# Count of distinct rows and with one from duplicates-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My column values

```
CustomerID
-----------
44468111
44468112
44468113
44468112
44468112
```

I need Count of total Customer ID's **Not Disctinct**.

Excpected Output:

```
Count(CustomerID's)
-------------------
3
```

Can you please help me out to get this. I am a newbie.
Thanks in Advance..!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want `3`, then you *do* want `distinct`:

```
select count(distinct CustomerID)
```

Comment: Soo simple and perfect solution :D. Thanks Gordon.